# Batch script: How to remove unwanted newline/tabs from end of text file

Tags: batch-file, curl, newline, whitespace

I am using batch scripts to automate a process that uses Curl to retrieve a license key that I will use later. The license key is 28,000 characters long (one line) so I cannot read this into a variable since 8,000 is the read-line limit. The license key comes with 4 "empty" lines. I say "empty" because the 4 lines actually have varying numbers of tabs. In order to use the license key later on I must remove these 4 lines. I've looked everywhere and haven't been able to find a solution.

Here is the Curl call from my batch script:

```
<nul set/P=licenseKey=>temp.txt
"%CURL_ExeFilePath%" -s --user <username> "<post_url>">>temp.txt
```

Here is the end of the `temp.txt` file that has the license key (obviously the `\t` & `\r\n` appear as whitespace):

```
/L0k1KCEkQjMwNCpdUVEuVDIoOl1BN0IrJE0iIAonMy4sKyE8REcnMCAgCg==}
\t\t\r\n
\t\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
```

I have little experience with batch scripts so that is where all of my research has been to find a solution. And I have no experience with Curl. I do not know if this should be solved using batch scripts or with Curl.

I need to remove all of the `\t` and `\r\n` from `temp.txt`

Comment: Instead of removing the disturbing characters/lines, I would try to avoid their creation... anyway, pure batch-files cannot handle such long lines, so you could perhaps go for VBScript, JavaScript or PowerShell, which are all native to Windows...

Comment: You could use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). I believe you want to remove all white space, in which case you could use `"%CURL_ExeFilePath%" -s --user <username> "<post_url>" | jrepl \s "" /m >>temp.txt`

Comment: I ended up switching to Powershell and am much happier with it's capabilities, thanks for commenting!